# Mock the ID returned by setInterval in JavaScript tests

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, jestjs, setinterval

Is there any way to mock the ID that `setInterval(...)` returns?

*Non-critical details for curiosity:*

I am testing a thunk action which passes that ID onto the global Redux state (to reset the interval later upon another action). Therefore, in tests, I would like to assert that my action was dispatched with precisely the same ID that had been returned from `setInterval(...)`.

I am currently using `jest.UseFakeTimers()` but there seems to be no API for mocking the interval ID, and upon observing the mock store, my action is dispatched with `undefined` as the interval ID payload.

Comment: Could you not just mock up a fake `setInterval()` that returns a random number, or `new Date().getTime()`?

Comment: Can you provide a couple of code snippets that show your mocking, etc?

Comment: @KarlM see my own answer to this question, it provides the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do this while still using `jest`'s API for faking timers.

```
const expectedIntervalId = 42;
jest.useFakeTimers();
setIntervalMock = (setInterval as jest.Mock);
setIntervalMock.mockImplementation(() => expectedIntervalId);
```

(NB: I use TypeScript)

Then I can e.g. verify that `clearInterval` was called with the same ID returned by the mocked function.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign `setInterval` to a variable, that variable contains the id. Check that with `var x = setInterval(() => console.log(x), 500);` in the console. Not sure though how to use that with `jest.UseFakeTimers` ... suppose the assignment should be in the callback.